# Input of type="number" jumps by two on Chrome (Mac OS Catalina 10.15)

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, input

Literally just

```
<input type="number" value="0" step="1" />
```

and it jumps by two for me on clicking both up and down (fine for arrow keys).

https://codepen.io/chandlervdw/pen/qBBdgZp?&editable=true

My coworkers are running the same version of Chrome as me (77.0.3865.90) and it jumps by one for them. The only difference is that I'm running Mac Catalina. Safari and Firefox are fine. How is this possible?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Not a one, @King11

Comment: Have you tried giving the `input` tag an id or class attribute? Do you have multiple `input` tags in your code?

Comment: And this only happens on Chrome on your Mac? Any extensions enabled in the browser? Same issue in incognito mode? What happens if you focus on the input and use the up or down keys to change the value?

Comment: try putting an explicit `step="1"` as an attribute on the input

Comment: Only on Chrome. Safari is fine. I confirmed that it happens in an incognito window with no extensions running. MacOS 10.15 (19A583)

Comment: @jtate no dice, I tried that, too! I'm so confused.

Comment: Same, also running Catalina. Safari jumps by one, Chrome by two.

Comment: If you use the arrow keys it does not, otherwise I have the same results as everyone else.

Comment: Same here updated now to Catalina and my app got the bug.

Comment: Same here, when pressing up (only clicking with the mouse the arrow in the input field) this input field will increase by `0.5` every time: `<input type="number" name="hours" step=".25" min="0" >`. This only happens with Chrome (most recent) on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: I've created a chromium bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012864

Comment: Can confirm this as well - after the Catalina update I have the same behavior.
(Bevor the update it worked fine)

Comment: Had a thought and actually the small arrows are not that user friendly and only a default thing. I changed the input to type="text" and added own buttons, then improved it further by adding a material UI component select: https://material-ui.com/components/selects/ with a dropdown. Bye bye input element :)

Comment: Experienced this bug also after upgrading the mac to Catalina. Fixed by updating Chrome and other browsers that uses Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

This bug was [reported on Chromium back in August](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=990863) and will be fixed in Chrome 78, which is stable today.